# How to feed data to model in CodeIgniter from different XMLs

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter application with a Xml_model:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Xml_model extends CI_Model {

        private $xml;

        public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          $this->xml = simplexml_load_file(base_url('xml/example.xml'));
        }

        public function getAllTags() {
          return array_unique($this->xml->xpath('descendant::Keyword'));
        }

        public function getLinks($nodeName) {
          return $this->xml->xpath('/Documents/TabPage/Node[@name="'.$nodeName.'"]/Links/Link');
        }

        public function getTabs() {
          return $this->xml->xpath('/Documents/TabPage/@name');
        }

        public function getNodes($tabName) {
          return $this->xml->xpath('/Documents/TabPage[@name="'.$tabName.'"]/Node/@name');
        }

        public function getPath($nodeName) {
          return $this->xml->xpath('/Documents/TabPage/Node[@name="'.$nodeName.'"]/Path');
        }

        public function search($tagName) {
          return $this->xml->xpath('//*[Keyword="'.$tagName.'"]/parent::Node/@name');
        }

}
?>
```

I want to be able to load this model with different XMLs. These XMLs are selected by a dropdown menu on the site. The XMLs are defining the navigation on the site so after selecting the XML from the dropdown the page reloads and does so with the newly selected XML. But I don't know how I can do that because I can't load a model with a parameter in CodeIgniter.

The dropdown:

```
  <div class="xml">
    <form method="post" id="xml-form">
      <select name="xml-select">
        <?php
          foreach(glob('xml/*.xml') as $filename) {
            echo '<option value="'.$filename.'">'.explode(".",explode("/",$filename)[1])[0].'</option>';
          }
        ?>
      </select>
      <button type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of to handle this.

One: Add an `init` function that takes the name of the file to load. Call this immediately after loading the model.

```
class Xml_model extends CI_Model 
{
    private $xml;

    public function init($file) {
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_file(base_url($file));
    }
```

The other option is to create a new library class instead of extending `CI_Model`. Based on what you show there's no obvious requirement for this to be a "Model" class.

Libraries **can** pass parameters to a constructor when being loaded. The only (very minor) tricky part I see is the call to `base_url()` will require you to get a reference to the CI "super object".  Or, you can resolve and pass the full path to the constructor thereby eliminating the need to call `base_url()` in your custom class.